# Is it possible to get a return value from an AcstionScript event handler?

Tags: xml, actionscript, event-handling, xml-parsing, return-value

I've been researching for 4 days to find an answer.  I came upon a few solutions for my code including some of the solutions given on this site; however, none of them seem to produce the result I'm trying to create on my site.  
The project is: I'm create a media player using XML data.  I've parsed the XML data in two different ways so far with goal of putting all of the returned data into a public array from one class so I can use it (the public array in that class) in an entirely different class.  
I've tried return values however, after experimenting I don't think it's even possible to get a return value from an event handler function.  I set a value as describe in a post on this site; however, the value only holds the XML data in that function, and I still can't use it as a public variable in other classes.

> public function getXML(xmlUrl:String):void{
>               var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
>               xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlUrl));
>               xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML2);
>           };
>       
>       
>   `public function LoadXML2(evt:Event):void{
>
>               _xmlData = XML(evt.currentTarget.data);
>
>               _albArray=[];
>
>                   _albArray = parseXML2(_xmlData);
>
>           };`

In the function LoadXML2 (the "2" is there because these are both second versions of my original code attempts)the value of _albArray is set and returns the object I need it to return.  The issue now is the value is only set in this function and I still can't access the returned data even though _albArray is a public variable of the class that is accessible by other classes.  Because it is an event handler I can't simply call the function itself and pull out the value from a separate class.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented above should work: _albArray will contain the correct value once the XML loads, and the value will be readable from other classes. Maybe the parseXML2 function isn't working? Or did I misunderstand your question?

You should also consider listening for IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, in case loading the XML fails.